# How to test for error condition from invalid input

Tags: unit-testing, go, testing, error-handling

I'm trying to do a test:

- The test cases are stored in a `slice` of `struct`s with `input` and `expect`.
- The expect can be `int` or `Error`.

The goal is to expect an Error if the input will cause an invalid result. I've learnt that it's not recommended to return an error string in Go. How can I expect an error whilst doing unit testing in Go?

Here's the code:

```golang
func arrIdx(arr []int, idx int) (int, error) {
    if idx >= 0 && idx < len(arr) {
        return arr[idx], nil
    }
    return 0, fmt.Errorf("This is an error")
}
func TestArrIdx(t *testing.T) {
    arr := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    tests := []struct {
        arr []int
        idx  int
        expect int // or an error
    }{
        {arr, len(arr) - 1, 5, nil},
        {arr, 1, 2, nil},
        // {arr, -1, 0, t.Error},
    }
    for _, test := range tests {
        testName := fmt.Sprintf("%d", test.input)
        t.Run(testName, func(t *testing.T) {
            got := arr[test.input]
            if got != test.expect {
                t.Errorf("got %v, want %v", got, test.expect)
            } else {
                fmt.Printf("got %v expect %v\n", got, test.expect)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Functions in golang can return multiple values. Normally you would return `(int, error)` in case your function can return errors, so that's what your test function should return as well. Check if error is nil, if it is then check result.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. If I return the error, what should the value of the test cases should I put? I've tried type error or t.Error but none is accepted.

Comment: Use a type that holds both an error and an int. If the error is nil, the expected result is the int. If the error is not nil, the error is the expected result.

Comment: You can only return string for unit test, even in function that return error type. [Error() string] is just interface that also contain error string e.g return error.New("uhmm.. error")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to do. Usually, you write methods that you want to test. Those methods have expected and unexpected results. You write unit tests to inject expected and unexpected input to generate those expected and unexpected results so your unit tests can make sure your methods are doing what they are built to do.

That being said, I could modify your block of code to handle errors, but I am not sure that is what you want:

```golang
package so_test

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
)

func TestArrIdx(t *testing.T) {
    arr := [5]int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    tests := []struct {
        input  int
        expect int
        err error
    }{
        {len(arr) - 1, 5, nil},
        {1, 2, nil},
        {0, 0, fmt.Errorf("this is an error")},
    }
    for _, test := range tests {
        testName := fmt.Sprintf("%d", test.input)
        t.Run(testName, func(t *testing.T) {
            if test.err != nil {
                t.Errorf("received error '%v'", test.err)
            } else {
                got := arr[test.input]
                if got != test.expect {
                    t.Errorf("got %v, want %v", got, test.expect)
                } else {
                    fmt.Printf("got %v expect %v\n", got, test.expect)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Or, maybe this is closer to what you were hoping to do?

```golang
package so_test

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
)

// our unit test of the DoSomething() function
func TestDoSomething(t *testing.T) {
    tests := []struct {
        input  int
        expect int
        err error
    }{
        {1, 2, nil},
        {2, 2, fmt.Errorf("this is an error")}, 
        {0, 0, fmt.Errorf("this is a DIFFERENT error")}, // will always fail
    }
    for _, test := range tests {
        result, err := DoSomething(test.input)
        if test.err != nil {
            if err == nil {
                t.Errorf("expected error '%v', received none\n", test.err)
            } else if err.Error() != test.err.Error() {
                t.Errorf("expected error: '%v', received '%v'\n", test.err, err)
            } else {
                fmt.Printf("expected error '%v', received error: '%v'\n", test.err, err)
            }
        } else {
            if result != test.expect {
                t.Errorf("got %v, want %v", result, test.expect)
            } else {
                fmt.Printf("got %v expect %v\n", result, test.expect)
            }
        }
    }
}

// our function to test
func DoSomething(something int) (int, error) {
    if something == 1 {
        return 2, nil;
    }

    return 0, fmt.Errorf("this is an error")
}
```

Comment: Thank you @sorens. Your 2nd example is what I want. I wasn't sure how to rewrite my function to return what error so I put in a "simplified" code inside the test function itself. I'm updating my question to make it clearer. Your solution works.